# How to correctly capture generator output in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, generator

I'm having some confusion with regards to a generator that I am using to create a sum of squares in python. Essentially I am iterating over vectors stored in a dictionary and finding the SS with another target vector.

I'm trying to code more pythonically by using list comprehension and generators but am struggling to understand how this is meant to work. The function that 'generates' just returns a string

```
<generator object distance.<locals>.operation at 0x00000181748E2048>
```

Which is obviously wrong. Any advice would be appreciated. Ideally want to output  the result of the SS operation but also interested in how I am misunderstanding this.

```
import math

v = [2,-2,1,3]
dv = {'a1':[0,1,3,5], 'a2':[2,5,6,7], 'a3':[1,-2,-3,2], 'a4':[2,2,1,1],
      'a5':[3,2,1,-1]}

def distance(v, dv):

    def operation(orig, nbr):
        yield [sum(math.sqrt(orig - nbr) for orig, nbr in zip(orig, nbr))]

    for k in sorted(dv):
        l = dv[k]
        list = operation(v,l)
        print(list)

distance(v, dv)
```

Comment: That is not how generators are supposed to be used. You can just change `yield` to `return` there, without any effect.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @RohitJain: Second part of your comment is untrue. Changing the `yield` to a `return` causes a `ValueError: math domain error` to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `yield` as you are returning a list.  The below `sum` function in `operation` is actually a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) than accomplishes the same thing.

Thus, `sum([x ** 0.5 for x in some_list])` becomes `sum(x for x in some_list)` using a generator expression which uses less memory.

```
def distance(v, dv):

    def operation(orig, nbr):
        return sum(abs(orig - nbr) ** 0.5 for orig, nbr in zip(orig, nbr))

    return [operation(v, dv[l]) for l in sorted(dv)]

>>> distance(v, dv)
[5.974691494688162, 6.8818192885643805, 4.0, 3.414213562373095, 5.0]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants something like `return sum(abs(orig - nbr) ** 0.5 for orig, nbr in zip(orig, nbr))` (or equivalently `return sum(math.sqrt(abs(orig - nbr)) for orig, nbr in zip(orig, nbr))`). Also, the `distance()` function itself doesn't return anything in the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you gentle oracles of the SO. I accepted Alexanders for conciseness, but both answers work well. I consider myself schooled once more :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `list(operation(v, l))`. Generators are yielded as a generator object and so you have to explicitly convert them to a list using `list()`.

Explained with examples [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#returning-iterable-objects-instead-of-lists).

Answer (score 3):

You're using generators wrong way. That `yield` will anyways only be executed once (provided you convert the return value to a list). And it's result in not even used in a generator expression.

You can change that code to something like this:

```
def operation(orig, nbr):
    for orig, nbr in zip(orig, nbr):
        yield math.sqrt(abs(orig - nbr))

for k in sorted(dv):
    l = dv[k]
    value = sum(operation(v,l))
    print(value)
```

Now, this is using the generator function properly. Everytime the `sum()` function needs the next value, the `for` loop inside `operation()` function will be executed `1 step`, and it will yield the next `sqrt` value, until it is exhausted.

Comment: The `yield` statement is never executed in the OP's code. When a generator function is called the first time, it returns a generator object.